# rails favicon issues, negative route constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I visit `domain.com/favicon.ico` it 404's, but `localhost:3000/favicon.ico` renders the favicon successfully.

I think it's catching on a root parameter route because the layout is rendered differently from the generic 404 page when I tried the fake route `/aliwejfl/aliwejf`.

```
get '/:nickname' => 'users#profile'
```

I know you can whitelist mime types in route constraints:

```
constraints(format: 'html') do
  # routes here
end
```

But is there a way to blacklist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out when writing the question. Forgot regular expressions were allowed.

```
constraints(format: /(?!ico)/) do
  # routes
end
```

That way `GET /not_favicon.ico` is a 404.